# Record data array on XCode from accelerometer

Tags: arrays, xcode, store

I am trying to create an app that will record the maximum G-Force and minimum G-Force during a given time. I've got the accelerometer to work and give the data (updated every 0.1s). I now want to store this data when the user clicks on "Record" and stop when the user clicks "Stop". I want an array that would give a new row every 0.1s. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *recordsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

CMMagnetometerData *data;

```
// where you get the data every 0.1 seconds
[recordsArray addObject:data];
```

Comment: Check how to detect motion in the [Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html). You use the usual accelerometer callbacks. Also, check out the [CMMotionManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.